# Sending HTML Email With Images Using PHP Mail

Tags: php, email

This code is Working:

```
<?php
// (A) MAIL SETTINGS
$mailTo = "emad.zedan@itisco.com.sa";
$mailSubject = "Test Mail With Image";
// (B) MAIL MESSAGE
// HOST THE IMAGE ON YOUR OWN SERVER!
// ALSO REMEMBER TO PROVIDE THE DIRECT LINK JUST-IN-CASE
$img = "https://emad-zedan.com/email/logo.png";
$mailBody = "<img src=".$img."><br>";
// (C) HEADER - HTML MAIL
$mailHead = implode("\r\n", [
      "MIME-Version: 1.0",
      "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8",
      "From: " . "uxui@emad-zedan.com"
]);
// (D) SEND
echo mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailBody, $mailHead)
? "OK" : "ERROR" ;

?>
```

but when I change it to something useful it does not send the second email:

```
$email_subject = 'ITIS Global Website Message- ' . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
    $email_message = 'ITIS Global - Website Get A Quote Message:' .
                '<br/>Full Name: ' . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname.
                '<br />International Phone: ' . $internationalphone .
                '<br />Email: ' . $email .
                '<br />Country: ' . $country .
                '<br />Company: ' . $company .
                '<br />Position: ' . $position .
                '<br />Solution: ' . $solution;

    $img1 = "https://emad-zedan.com/email/logo.png";
    $img2 = "https://emad-zedan.com/email/in.png";
    $img3 = "https://emad-zedan.com/email/f.png";
    $img4 = "https://emad-zedan.com/email/t.png";
    $img5 = "https://emad-zedan.com/email/y.png";

    
    $email_message_confirmation = "<div>" .
                        "<div style='font-size:20px;padding:10px 0px;'>Thank you for contacting us!</div><br />" .
                        "<div>We will responed to you on the given contact information as soon as possible, We collected this infromtion from you:</div>" .
                        "<table border='0'>" .
                        "<tr width='150'>" .
                        "<td><strong>Full Name: </strong></td>" .
                        "<td>" . $firstname . "&nbsp;" . $lastname . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>" .
                        "<tr width='150'>" .
                        "<td><strong>International Phone: </strong></td>" .
                        "<td>" . $internationalphone . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>" .
                        "<tr width='150'>" .
                        "<td><strong>Email: </strong></td>" .
                        "<td>" . $email . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>" .
                        "<tr width='150'>" .
                        "<td><strong>Country: </strong></td>" .
                        "<td>" . $country . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>" .
                        "<tr width='150'>" .
                        "<td><strong>Company: </strong></td>" .
                        "<td>" . $company . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>" .
                        "<tr width='150'>" .
                        "<td><strong>Position: </strong></td>" .
                        "<td>" . $position . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>" .
                        "<tr width='150'>" .
                        "<td><strong>Solution: </strong></td>" .
                        "<td>" . $solution . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>" .
                        "<tr>" .
                        "<td colspan='2'><br /><strong>For more information, please use the following contact information:</strong>" .
                        "<br />Email: <a href='mailto:uxui@emad-zedan.com'>uxui@emad-zedan.com</a>" .
                        "<br />Office: Building No. 6427, Prince Muhammad Ibn Saad Ibn Abdulaziz Road, Riyadh, KSA" .
                        "<br />Phone: +92 000 9407" .
                        "<br />Mobile: +962 77 050 2845" .
                        "<br />Website: <a href='https://itisco.com.sa' target='_blank'>itisco.com.sa</a>" .
                        "<br />" .
                        "<br /><a href='https://itisco.com.sa' target='_blank'><img src=". $img1 ." width='374' height='73' /></a>" .
                                    "<br /><br /><a href='#' target='_blank'><img src=". $img2 ." width='25' height='25'></a>" .
                                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' target='_blank'><img src=". $img3 ." width='25' height='25'></a>" .
                                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' target='_blank'><img src=". $img4 ." width='25' height='25'></a>" .
                                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' target='_blank'><img src=". $img5 ." width='25' height='25'></a>" .
                                    "</td>" .
                                    "</tr>" .
                                    "</table>" .
                                    "</div>";

    // The content-type header must be set when sending HTML email
    $headers1 = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "Content-Type: text/html;Charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "From: " . "uxui@emad-zedan.com";
    mail("uxui@emad-zedan.com", $email_subject, $email_message, $headers1);
    
    $mailHead = implode("\r\n", [
        "MIME-Version: 1.0",
        "Content-Type: text/html;Charset=utf-8",
        "From: " . "uxui@emad-zedan.com"
    ]);

    echo mail($email, "ITIS Global", $email_message_confirmation, $mailHead) ? "OK" : "ERROR" ;
```

I search every little code on stackoverflow and contacted my support, he gave me the working code when I recode it as I need in my project it does not send the email.

anybody can solve this issue? I know that the problem is in the sending images using PHP mail, but the first code is working!!!!

Comment: What is the value of `$email` ?

Comment: emad.zedan@itisco.com.sa

Comment: this code read post from a form. it can be any email. as long as from header is from my website email like uxui@emad-zedan.com

Comment: if i comment the images part from email body the second email is sent successfully. but i need to add logo and socil icons

Comment: no nothing in junk